# Restore Bacpac File in SSMS Using Powershell or Command Line in Windows

Tags: sql-server, command-line, ssms, windows-scripting

I have to restore bacpac file into SSMS in local machine using a script or a command line,

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Aside... SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is just a client program for managing SQL Server instances. i.e.: SSMS itself doesn't actually host any databases. If you want to restore (import) a bacpac file you need to have a SQL Server instance somewhere that's hosting the target database, you just use SSMS to manage that process.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning can we restore Database in Sql Server and how to do it can you please please help me with this using powershell